# can I cut back hydrangea flowers?

Tags: hydrangea

we had an unusually dry season and my hydrangea blooms looks burnt I have noticed new growth is it ok to dead head the old flowers

Answer (score 0):

All plants do better if one takes the flowers off. An awful lot of energy by a plant is put into seed making (flowers) and once plants have set seed ( older flowers) they kinda take a break, stop making flowers and if we were talking about annuals they simply die. Hydrangeas do better if one prunes the flowers off (then uses them for vases or to dry). To allow the Hydrangea flowers to go all the way to making seed is a waste of energy for the plant.

Absolutely, cut those flowers off! Next year get them off sooner so all that energy that went into making seed would then be used by the plant to grow larger, healthier and even make a few more blooms. Gorgeous as dried flowers!!

Comment: Posting the [same answer](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/27446/26) to different questions is a sure sign that they're duplicates. Please use your close votes in this situation. Thanks!